# Run a command right before a script exits due to failure

Tags: shell, unix, zsh, exit, exit-code

Let's say there's this script

```
#!/bin/zsh
python -c 'a'
```

which will fail since `a` isn't defined. Just before the shell script exits, I want to run a command, say `echo bye`. How can that be achieved?

Flow is to be:

- Python command above fails.
- `bye` appears in terminal.
- The zsh script exits.

I'd prefer it to affect the python command as little as possible such as indent, putting it in an if block, checking its exit code etc. In real life, the command is in fact multiple commands.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `zsh`, but `bash` has a `trap` command might be relevant. Maybe `zsh` has something similar?

Comment: `trap 'echo bye' 0`

Comment: thanks @WilliamPursell, added an answer with what I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script you posted, the fact that the shell exits is unrelated to any error. The shell would exit, because the last argument hast been executed. Take for instance the script

```
#!/bin/zsh
python -c 'a'
echo This is the End
```

The final echo will always be exeuted, independent of the  `python` command. To cause the script to exit, when *python* returns a non-zero exit code, you would write something like

```
#!/bin/zsh
python -c 'a' || exit $?
echo Successful
```

If you want to exit a script, whenever *the first one* of the commands produces a non-zeror exit status, **AND** at the same time want to print a message, you can use the `TRAPZERR` callback:

```
#!/bin/zsh
TRAPZERR() {
  echo You have an unhandled non-zero exit code in your otherwise fabulous script
  exit $?
}
python -c 'a'
echo Only Exit Code 0 encountered
```